# How to deny location permission forever after first deny on Android like on IOS in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, permissions

I'm building an app that asks permission to access location on different screens, the problem occurs if I deny permission on screen 1 then when I get to screen 2 it still asks permission again. This problem occurs on android and i found out that android will deny forever if denied 2 or more times. How can I make it permanently denied after only 1 first denition? Please tell me the solution. Thanks

Comment: This is a system functionality and you cannot change anything about it until and unless google makes changes to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So i will have to edit my source code.